# Why, when I set `preserve_keys = true` with PHP's array_slice(), are my array keys still getting reset?

Tags: php, arrays, slice

I have an existing array with keys as such:

```
$characters = array(
    "43424" => "Jerry",
    "45444" => "George",
    "16332" => "Elaine",
    "09766" => "Kramer",
    "75443" => "Newman",
);
```

I'd like to split these arrays into 2 with an integer and print them as such:

```
$splitter = 3;

// First half
print_r(array_slice($characters, 0, $splitter, true));
// Second half
print_r(array_slice($characters, $splitter, true));
```

In this situation, the first `array_slide` - the 'first half' - works, but not the 2nd - in fact the 2nd line only returns 1 array item.

The results from above are

```
Array
(
    [43424] => Jerry
    [45444] => George
    [16332] => Elaine
)
```

and

```
Array
(
   [0] => Kramer
)
```

If I remove the `trues` from above I get all results displaying, but of course without their original array keys.

Would anyone know what's happening with the 2nd `array_slice()` and what I could do to fix it?

Comment: Your 3. parameter is wrong. It should be integer, not boolean `print_r(array_slice($characters, $splitter, NULL, true));` or `print_r(array_slice($characters, $splitter, $splitter, true));`

Comment: `$preserve_keys` is the *4th* parameter, you have to actually pass it as the 4th parameter, not just wish for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP array\_slice() null length results in empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321416/php-array-slice-null-length-results-in-empty-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That:

```
// First half
print_r(array_slice($characters, 0, $splitter, true));
// Second half
print_r(array_slice($characters, $splitter, true));
```

should be:

```
// First half
print_r(array_slice($characters, 0, $splitter, true));
// Second half
print_r(array_slice($characters, $splitter, null, true));
```

You missed `$length` parameter, so `true` meant `$length = 1` with default `$preserve_keys` (false)